# OctoberCMS (Laravel) + Vue.js + Tailwind CSS Best Setup

Tags: laravel, vue.js, microservices, octobercms, tailwind-css

I am new with OctoberCMS. There are few tutorials in the internet. May I ask what is the best setup may I use or possible setup may I use with this web tech stacks?

We have a project and the requirement is we need to use octobercms so that's why we have to used this octobercms.

---

Possible Setup:

1. Micro Service Setup?

   - Two seperate folder for OctoberCMS and Vue.js. The communication would be an API Request calls.

---

Then for the deployment part for the production, we will use the dist folder from Vue.js Folder. I'm not 100% sure but I think this will be my initial thought that will be possible.

May I ask for any suggestions or clarifications on what will I use project setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While it would be entirely possible to have two separate web properties with October providing the API, you can also just use Vue within an October CMS theme itself. See https://github.com/scottbedard/vuetober for more information on doing that.

If your project is more of a traditional CMS requirement then I would recommend at least trying the Vuetober approach. If it's a lot more complex and is mostly utilizing October for its powerful backend features, then the API-only approach could work fine too.

The main reason you'd want to go with running vuetober is if you were going to be utilizing the AJAX framework provided by October. You can still technically use it even when October is being run as a headless CMS just providing an API, but it gets more complicated with CORS and some other stuff you have to setup to make sure it works properly.